# unexpected crash occurs while distributing an app in xcode with flutter

Tags: flutter, xcode, distribute

part of error message below

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [7183]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               15.3 (22618)
Build Info:            IDEApplication-22618000000000000~2 (15E204a)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       863955376
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-03-26 13:15:46.1155 +0900
OS Version:            macOS 14.4 (23E214)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        4F2D1206-C126-C795-83FF-9BBED08B23C6


Time Awake Since Boot: 690 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        10  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   Xcode [7183]

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Application Specific Signatures:
success

Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e1f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184250b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184246e34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e578 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18435e058 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x18435c91c __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x18435be0c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   HIToolbox                              0x18eaf7000 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
8   HIToolbox                              0x18eaf6e3c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 648
9   HIToolbox                              0x18eaf6b94 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
10  AppKit                                 0x187bb4970 _DPSNextEvent + 660
11  AppKit                                 0x1883a6dec -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 700
12  DVTKit                                 0x103527858 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 300
13  AppKit                                 0x187ba7cb8 -[NSApplication run] + 476
14  DVTKit                                 0x103526b24 -[DVTApplication run] + 60
15  AppKit                                 0x187b7ef54 NSApplicationMain + 880
16  dyld                                   0x183ef60e0 start + 2360

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e1f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184250b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184246e34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e578 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18435e058 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x18435c91c __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x18435be0c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   Foundation                             0x18548f028 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   DTDeviceKitBase                        0x1133c3300 +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 148
9   Foundation                             0x185488520 __NSThread__start__ + 716
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427ef94 _pthread_start + 136
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d34 thread_start + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e1f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184250b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184246e34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e578 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18435e058 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x18435c91c __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x18435be0c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   Foundation                             0x18548f028 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   DTDeviceKitBase                        0x1133ce6c8 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 228
9   Foundation                             0x185488520 __NSThread__start__ + 716
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427ef94 _pthread_start + 136
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d34 thread_start + 8

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184249358 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                         0x18438730c __CFSocketManager + 640
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427ef94 _pthread_start + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d34 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e1f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184250b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184246e34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e578 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18435e058 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x18435c91c __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x18435be0c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   AppKit                                 0x187cddcb4 _NSEventThread + 144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427ef94 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d34 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e1f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184250b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184246e34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e578 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18435e058 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x18435c91c __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x18435be0c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   CFNetwork                              0x1897f5890 0x189595000 + 2492560
8   Foundation                             0x185488520 __NSThread__start__ + 716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427ef94 _pthread_start + 136
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d34 thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e1f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184250b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184246e34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e578 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18435e058 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x18435c91c __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x18435be0c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1843d9e3c CFRunLoopRun + 64
8   SwiftPM                                0x159d85cc4 closure #1 in FSEventStream.start() + 224
9   SwiftPM                                0x159d547ac closure #1 in Thread.init(task:) + 104
10  SwiftPM                                0x159d54574 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28
11  SwiftPM                                0x159d54914 @objc ThreadImpl.main() + 44
12  Foundation                             0x185488520 __NSThread__start__ + 716
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427ef94 _pthread_start + 136
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d34 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184246a60 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427ec20 pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18418ba20 abort + 180
3   IDEKit                                 0x10809fb64 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 972
4   IDEKit                                 0x10809ffa4 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 872
5   DVTFoundation                          0x10469273c _DVTAssertionHandler + 424
6   DVTFoundation                          0x1046928bc _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 196
7   DVTFoundation                          0x104558410 +[DVTFilePath _filePathForParent:pathString:] + 512
8   DVTFoundation                          0x104558a9c -[DVTFilePath filePathForRelativePathString:] + 48
9   IDEFoundation                          0x109ba1edc -[IDEDistributionProcessingPipelineContext packagePathForVariant:] + 768
10  IDEFoundation                          0x109bb8514 -[IDEDistributionCreateIPAStep name] + 88
11  IDEFoundation                          0x109b9fe40 __98-[IDEDistributionProcessingPipeline observationForPhaseStateChanges:stepIndex:pipelineStepsCount:]_block_invoke + 96
12  DVTFoundation                          0x10469e5e4 -[NSObject(DVTObservingConvenience) _dvt_newObserverForKeyPath:options:owner:creationBacktrace:withHandlerBlock:] + 380
13  DVTFoundation                          0x10469f3ac -[NSObject(DVTObservingConvenience) dvt_newObserverForKeyPath:options:withHandlerBlock:] + 124
14  IDEFoundation                          0x109b9fd04 -[IDEDistributionProcessingPipeline observationForPhaseStateChanges:stepIndex:pipelineStepsCount:] + 152
15  IDEFoundation                          0x109ba0078 -[IDEDistributionProcessingPipeline processForThinningVariant:distributionItem:stepClass:stepIndex:pipelineStepsCount:error:] + 420
16  IDEFoundation                          0x109b9f80c -[IDEDistributionProcessingPipeline process:] + 1132
17  IDEFoundation                          0x109954594 -[IDEDistributionPackagingStep loadDrivableFromExportOptions:error:] + 204
18  IDEFoundation                          0x109a1c2a8 -[IDEDistributionDriver runWithDestinationPath:wantsExportStep:] + 1992
19  IDEFoundation                          0x109cd881c closure #1 in RecoverableDistributionDriver.run() + 188
20  IDEFoundation                          0x109c6cb84 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable () -> () + 28
21  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1840cc750 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
22  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1840ce3e8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
23  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1840d1580 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 928
24  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1840dfea8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 392
25  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1840e06b8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427afd0 _pthread_wqthread + 228
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d28 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 18:: ExceptionSafeThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1842419ec __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427f55c _pthread_cond_wait + 1228
2   CoreSymbolicationDT                    0x103068fc4 CSCppExceptionSafeThread::runloop() + 68
3   CoreSymbolicationDT                    0x10306892c thread_runloop_init(CSCppExceptionSafeThread*) + 32
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427ef94 _pthread_start + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d34 thread_start + 8

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e1f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184250b24 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x184246e34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18423e578 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18435e058 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x18435c91c __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x18435be0c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1843d9e3c CFRunLoopRun + 64
8   DebugSymbolsDT                         0x102b54a08 SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 580
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18427ef94 _pthread_start + 136
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x184279d34 thread_start + 8


Thread 10 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00006000004dd4ee   x5: 0x000000013a8b8e34   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000327c615c8
    x8: 0xb936404fd96f3103   x9: 0xb936404cfea90103  x10: 0x000000015291efb2  x11: 0x000000000000003f
   x12: 0x0000000000000012  x13: 0x000000015d1acf10  x14: 0x00000001ebfa46a0  x15: 0x00000001ebfa46a0
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001f62f6c30  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000327c63000  x21: 0x000000000002a207  x22: 0x0000000327c630e0  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000060000c009200  x27: 0x0000600005206840
   x28: 0x00000001ebf8d408   fp: 0x0000000327c62210   lr: 0x000000018427ec20
    sp: 0x0000000327c621f0   pc: 0x0000000184246a60 cpsr: 0x40001000
   far: 0x0000000000000000  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

I made a app with flutter and we get started to build ipa so I get done all settings and when I press 'distribute app' in xcode, It occurs some crash with message above I searched some solution like changing optimization level but it doesn't work I don't know how to do pls help me xcode version : 15.3

Comment: It happens to me. I've tried to find the reason...

same version of your xcode, developed by flutter